# Problem with assembling function in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

```
    -- Function: adempiere.qtyondateorg2(integer, timestamp with time zone, character varying)

-- DROP FUNCTION adempiere.qtyondateorg2(integer, timestamp with time zone, character varying);

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION adempiere.qtyondateorg2(
    product_id integer,
    indate timestamp with time zone,
    org_id character varying)
  RETURNS numeric AS
$BODY$
DECLARE
    Quantity        NUMERIC := 0;
    vP              NUMERIC := 0;
BEGIN

  SELECT Aux.M_Product_ID, SUM(Aux.QtyOnHand) AS QtyOnHand 
    INTO vP, Quantity FROM

  (SELECT DISTINCT    '1', s.M_Product_ID, SUM(s.QtyOnHand) AS QtyOnHand, l.M_Warehouse_ID, l.M_Locator_ID
          FROM    M_Storage s
    INNER JOIN    M_Locator l ON s.M_Locator_ID = l.M_Locator_ID
    INNER JOIN    M_Warehouse w ON l.M_Warehouse_ID=w.M_Warehouse_ID
         WHERE    s.M_Product_ID = Product_ID
         AND      w.lbr_WarehouseType NOT LIKE '3RD'
        AND l.AD_Org_ID IN (org_id)
      GROUP BY    s.M_Product_ID, l.M_Warehouse_ID, l.M_Locator_ID, l.AD_Org_ID
UNION
        SELECT    '2', t.M_Product_ID, SUM(t.MovementQty) * -1 AS QtyOnHand, l.M_Warehouse_ID, t.M_Locator_ID
          FROM    M_Transaction t
    INNER JOIN    M_Locator l ON t.M_Locator_ID = l.M_Locator_ID
    INNER JOIN    M_Warehouse w ON l.M_Warehouse_ID=w.M_Warehouse_ID
         WHERE    TRUNC(t.MovementDate) >= TRUNC(InDate)
           AND    w.lbr_WarehouseType NOT LIKE '3RD'
           AND    t.M_Product_ID = Product_ID
           AND l.AD_Org_ID IN ( org_id )
      GROUP BY    t.M_Product_ID, l.M_Warehouse_ID, t.M_Locator_ID, l.AD_Org_ID) Aux

      GROUP BY M_Product_ID;

      IF (Quantity IS NULL) THEN
    Quantity := 0;
      END IF;

      RETURN Quantity;
END
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
  COST 100;
ALTER FUNCTION adempiere.qtyondateorg2(integer, timestamp with time zone, character varying)
  OWNER TO adempiere;
```

I am having problem in the following function, in the parameter AD_Org_ID, I would like to pass as string as below:

```
  select adempiere.qtyondateorg2 (2045480, '31/12/2018',' 2000002, 2000003');
```

However I get the following error:

ERROR: operator does not exist: numeric = character varying
LINE 10: AND l.AD_Org_ID IN (org_id)

TIP: No operator matches the given name and argument type (s). You might need to add explicit type casts.

Any help to form the function in the right way? Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use the `IN` operator in this way:

```
create or replace function wrong_func(org_id varchar)
returns boolean language plpgsql as $$
declare
    ad_org_id numeric = 1;
begin
    -- this raises an error as ad_org_id is numeric and org_id is varchar
    return ad_org_id in (org_id);
end $$;

select wrong_func('1,2,3');

ERROR:  operator does not exist: numeric = character varying
LINE 1: SELECT ad_org_id in (org_id)
                         ^
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

Use a numeric array as an argument in the way like this:

```
create or replace function correct_func(org_id numeric[])
returns boolean language plpgsql as $$
declare
    ad_org_id numeric = 1;
begin
    return ad_org_id = any(org_id);
end $$;

select correct_func('{1,2,3}')

 correct_func 
--------------
 t
(1 row)
```

Comment: Thank you very much, @Klin!

It worked perfectly this way.